# Formatting a while loop in php

Tags: php

I am trying to format the output of a while loop in php. When displaying the results of the while loop it is just one long list. I would like to split it up into columns. Here is my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM refdb ORDER BY referral";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql)or die(mysqli_error());
echo "<form action='test2.php' method='get'>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

echo '<input type="checkbox" name="tag[]" value="' . $row[referral] . '">' . $row[referral] . '</label></br>';  


}

echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" Value="Submit"/>';
```

It returns the results as a checkbox options in a a form.

(This is my first post, sorry if I mangled it. Any help would be greatly appreciated)

Comment: The simplest answer is take the </br> out of the echo string.

Comment: What is your question?  It sounds like you're looking to style your markup, which would be done on the HTML and CSS, not in PHP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting a PHP Array into Columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428723/sorting-a-php-array-into-columns)

Comment: right now they display as a single column column with about 50 entries. I would like to display as 5 columns with 10 entries in each.

Answer (score 0):

This is on a templating or output context. When in this context it is better to use the alternate syntax control structures (assuming you are not inside a function/method - which you should not be):

```
<?php while(EXPRESSION): ?>
<div class="somehtml">
   <?php echo $something ?>
   <a href="<?php echo $theURl ?>"><?php echo $theLabel ?></a>
</div>
<?php endwhile ?>
```

Now in terms of your specific problem... Assuming the size of the result set is reasonable i would fetch them all into an array first:

```
$results = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $results[] = $row;
}
```

After that you can use [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) to transform it into an array of columns:

```
$columns = array_chunk($results, 5);
```

Then you can output them:

```
<?php foreach($columns as $rows): ?>
    <div class="col">
    <?php foreach($rows as $row): ?>
        <input type="checkbox" name="tag[]" value="<?php echo $row[referral]?>"> 
        <label><?php echo $row[referral] ?></label></br>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I don't what I'm messing up, but this isn't working for me. It still just shows up as one long column. instead of multiple columns.

Comment: Well you would need to style the `div`s containing the elements, ohterwise it would appear as a single long column.